# Importing raspi data from sd card to computer

Tags: pi-3, data-transfer

My sd card with raspbian installed is not displaying the data stored on it, such as files in the home directory etc.

Inserting it into a computer causes the RECOVERY drive to show up, which looks as following:

[image]

none of the folders contain any of my data. can I assume that it is lost or is there a way to recover it?

Comment: You should be able to see the files on any Linux computer (even if you have used NOOBS which makes it more difficult)

Comment: What operating system is running on the computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install EXT2FSD on your windows. Then you can copy paste the files inside. Before doing so make sure your PC is free from harmful malware and viruses. Or you can jack that SDCARD in another Linux OS and enter the folder directly. The folder ROOTFS has your files in. The picture you gave is boot partition.

Answer (score 3):

Raspbian's main partition (containing home and everything) cannot be seen by a Windows computer unfortunately.

A Linux PC would see it fine, and probably a Chromebook or a Mac as well.
If you want to transfer files, you can use a USB flash drive, or copy the files to the Pi's boot partition.

Comment: And, it's time to stop using NOOBS.